# Always check if word entered is in my array and check for all combinations

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, string

I've got msg as a user input, but I want to make it so when a user enters anything like these included in the array, it alerts the user.

This is what I have used, but I'd have to then write this for every combination of words, so below is how I would like to make it simple and more efficient but don't know how to.

```
msg.includes('foo');
```

```
let warns = ['no', 'hello', 'foo', 'foobar', 'fooo']

    if (msg.includes(warns)) {
        alert("This was used!")

    }
```

Comment: Check for all combinations means what?

Comment: I want to check if the word entered is in the array, whether it is combined with other words or not, eg. thisisfoo     or then foo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the array method [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) that will check if at least one element passes for a given condition:

```
if (warns.some(warn => warn.includes(msg))) {
    alert("This was used!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this might help

```
    function includes(message,array,callback){   
    for(var i in array){
    if(array[i].includes(message)){
        callback(message)
        }
    }
}

includes("Awan",["Awan is a cast","Malik Awan","Don't","Pakistan"],(message)=>{console.log(  `${message} is already used`)})
```